# mongodb bulk inserts from apache PIG

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, apache-pig

Does com.mongodb.hadoop.pig.MongoInsertStorage (for PIG) from mongo-hadoop support batch/bulk inserting? If so, how to enable that? I searched and couldn't find any documentation on it.

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not support batch writes, as such.  It delegates to RecordWriter which passes things down the line in hadoop.

Comment: Any recommendations on open source packages to do this? If not, I will start writing one.. Thanks.